# Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0 when Oracle 11 and 12 are installed

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, odp.net

On my local machine, witch I use for ASP.NET Web Development,  I have several Oracle 11 Client (11.2.0.1, 11.2.0.2, 11.2.0.3).  My website Use the Oracle.DataAccess.Dll (ODP.NET all 32bits)

I just installed the Oracle 12c ODPwithODAC package 32bits.

And now the website that use the Oracle.DataAccess.dll 11.2.  doesn't work anymore. I have this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
>      Oracle.Web.Security.OracleMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) +0
>      Oracle.Web.Security.OracleMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +105
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AuthenticateUsingMembershipProvider(AuthenticateEventArgs e) +59
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs e) +113
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +119
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +75
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +114
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +164

Comment: looks like the version of the assembly has changed so you need to update it in your config

Comment: @dansasu11 The Things is I want my WebApp to run under my 11.2 Oracle Client even if I Installed a 12.1 version Side by Side.

Comment: Have you tried to copy the exact version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll for 11.2 into your bin directory?

Comment: @CodeZombie Yeah All my Reference are set to "Local Copy" so when i Build my solution, all the dll are copied to my bin folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, with the [Oracle Home Selector](https://oratools.codeplex.com/), I Choose the Oracle Home that i wanted.

In Visual Studio, I set the property "Specific Version" to "false" on my "Oracle.DatabaseAccess" reference.

[image: Property pane]

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. I'm using Oracle 12c and I had to change the 'Platform target' to x64. So check the version of your system and change that to x86 or x64.

Comment: Even if you change the platform be sure that in your project propeties, in the build option tab, the "Prefer 32-bit" option is not check if you wanna use x64.

Comment: why would someone be forced to convert project platform to 32-bit? Doesn't Oracle have data access components for NET x64 applications?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before. I have set the startup project (in my case console application) to prefer 32 bit checkbox checked in the build tab (You can find this tab by right clicking on `project` and select `properties`).

Answer (score 1):

Remove Oracle.DatabaseAccess reference from your project and install it again from manage nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I resolved it with following steps:

1. In Solution Explorer, right click on Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core
2. Click Properties
3. Copy path
4. Go to above path and copy "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
5. Paste into project bin folder

[image]

[image]